# Adb shell gives root acess instead of shell access

Tags: android, shell, adb

I am trying to connect to my Android 6.0 Arm V7a emulator, I have updated sdk and system image to the latest version.
When I'm trying to get shell access through `adb shell`, what I get is root access prompt `#` instead of ordinary shell `$`.

what I get:

```
root@generic:/ #
whoami
root
```

what I need is:

```
shell@generic:/ $
whoami
shell
```

How can i fix that?
I have to say that I tried `adb unroot` command and it did not work.

Comment: Try running `su shell`

Comment: @jackgu1988 Great it worked ! give that as an answer so i can accept it .

Comment: Just did, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `su shell`. More information regarding the `su` command here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html